# How To Integrate Someone else's Twitter feed In my Android Application

Tags: android, eclipse, twitter-feed

Basically I want to be able to show this twitter feed: https://twitter.com/aaroadwatch. I have looked at many tutorials but I haven't found one that shows how to integrate someone else s news feed. Anyone got any links out there, and is there a simple way to do this? I'm using eclipse create this app.

Answer (score 0):

Using Twitter's own Fabric SDK it's as simple as writing 3 lines of code. 
First you have to integrate Fabric SDK into your project

1) Setup Fabric using the official instructions: https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/twitter.html

2) 
then you can show a user's timeline in a ListView using this code:

```
final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
            .screenName("aaroadwatch")
            .build();
        final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(this)
            .setTimeline(userTimeline)
            .build();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

you can read more how to integrate it into your app https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-timelines.html